# How to type this symbol like a “u”

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

Could anybody tell me how to type the symbol like a “u”?

The figure is below

[image]

Comment: Check the question linked in my comment; it's not specifically there, but you can get it with `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` and `\mathscr{U}`.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that the question has been closed: we try our best not to scatter information. Be welcome and don't fear to ask.